# How can we give FilterPattern in yaml file in Cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, monitoring, health-check, cloudwatch-alarms

My CloudWatch Alarms are not working because the Health Check Lambda was displaying 500 or 400 as response but not error. Even after below fix, I don't see alarms. While I see 500s in Cloudwatch. What am I missing?

```
  AppHealthMetricFilter:
    DependsOn:
      - ApiGwName
    Type: AWS::Logs::MetricFilter
    Properties: 
      LogGroupName: !Sub '/aws/lambda/${HealthCheckLambdaName}'
      FilterPattern: ?"error" ?"500" ?"400"
      MetricTransformations: 
        - MetricValue: "1"
          MetricNamespace: !Ref CustomMetricNS
          MetricName: !Ref CustomMetricName
```

[image]

Comment: What is alarm state in cloudwatch console?